# dependent job not starting due to s condition

Tags: autosys

```
Job B 
Condition s(Job A, 9.00) 
Start time: 9:15
```

Job A has run within 9 hours. Sometimes the Job A starts running again just before the scheduled start time of Job B (9:15). Because of this, Job B cannot start as Job A is RU instead of SU.

What kind of condition on Job B would solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is your jobB should be really dependent with the success of jobA? if yes, then all you need to do is to wait for the jobA to be completed, and jobB will automatically start after that. If no, you can simply remove the jobA in the run condition of jobB and remain the start time of jobB as 9:15. Also, are your jobs reside in the same box? Is your jobA has multiple run time in a day?

Comment: The job B should depend on the previous run of Job A (within 9 hours). Job A runs multiple times a day. Job A and B are in different boxes

Comment: What I'm looking is some '&' condition along with this condition s(Job A, 9.00) which would trigger the job B even if job A is in RU state

Comment: I see, so it's not an option to remove the jobA in the run condition of the jobB. As far as I know, the only available conditions in autosys are Done (d), Success (s), Failure (f), Terminated (t), and Not Running (n). Can you try to use "Not Running" and put exclamation '!' before it "s(Job A, 9.00) | !n(Job A). I haven't tried this one though so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: If the 1st I've given didn't work, you can create a script that'll monitor the status of Job A. This script will be in a new job (Job C) that will run at 9:15 to monitor the status of Job A. In addition, you need to update the condition of your Job B to 's(Job C)'. If Job C sees that job A's already in SU or RU state at 9:15, then it will turn to SU, else it will fail. When the Job C already in SU, the Job B will automatically run, else, it will turn to IN. The draw back of this is that once Job C already inactive, it will not run again for the day even Job C already completed (past 9:15)